# Derivative of positive function is positive close to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Assume you have a function $f \mapsto \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$, $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$. Additionally $f'(0) = 0$. I want to prove that exists a $x^* > 0$ such that $f(x)$ is increasing for $0 \le x < x^*$.

I have been toying with the theorem of permanence of sign of the derivative (which is continuos) and the fact that the function must be positive, but I can't quite get there.

Is it even true? If not, would be cool to have a counterexample :)

Comment: Just put a function oscillating near zero between the graphs of $x^2$ and $x^4$.

Comment: @Hellen Ah, right. Very nice. Make that an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hellen mentioned in the comments, a function oscillating near zero between the graphs of $x^2$ and $x^4$ is a counterexample.

Function is positive, and is $0$ in $0$. But since it's continuously oscillating between the two graphs, there is no interval containing zero in which it is increasing.